# How to connect 2 devices with lan cable

Tags: lan

I want to connect my HP printer and router connection to my PC. I have 1 Lan port and i want to connect both the device. I have purchase RJ 45 1 to 2 way splitter.

[image]

With the above splitter im trying to connect my printer and internet. Problem im having is 1 time 1 device active. When need to print i have to remove the router cable and when need internet i have to remove printer cable. Any way to fix with this device. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to buy a USB to Ethernet Adapter from amazon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can return that device, do so straight away.
Ethernet doesn't conveniently split like that.

*From comments, it appears there are two types of these - neither are appropriate.*

One type is designed to be used in pairs to *join* two low-speed ethernet connections so they can travel over one long cable. You then *split* them again into two cables at the far end.
See [Ethernet Switch vs. Hub vs. Splitter: What’s the Difference?](https://www.maketecheasier.com/ethernet-switch-vs-hub-vs-splitter/)

The other type "shares" the single cable between two devices plugged into the double end… but you can only use one at any given time.
I absolutely cannot see the point of this at all ;)

What you need is an [Ethernet Switch](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/ethernet-switch) (definition) + [Amazon shopping link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Network-Hubs-Switches/b?ie=UTF8&node=430573031).
Plug the router, computer & printer into any three sockets.

At most basic, you can get a switch for under $£€ 5 but it's probably better to get one with a name you've heard of.

Comment: Worse - its kinda like "you unplug or turn off one machine at a time"

Comment: It's like a kind of manual token ring… but worse ;) …and actually more expensive than the very cheapest switches.

Comment: Oh there's splitters too, which are also terrible but make more sense

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - yeah, I just found the other type on Amazon. Who on earth would want one of those one at a time devices? The 'splitters' I'm talking about above are opposite, join 2 two-pairs to travel over one 4-pair, then re-split at the far end. I didn't know the 'one at a time' devices existed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I've added both types to the answer. Seems these things are only there to trap the unwary ;)

Comment: ... I spent far too much time wondering that, and I don't have a great answer.... I'd guess almost you want gigabit, and want to save wear and tear on switching cables, or you have three segments you want to switch between. In every single scenario, a switch makes more sense. As with my special 2 pair ethernet cables some things are just meant to keep me up at night wondering :D

Comment: Switches are just so darn cheap these days… if in doubt, buy a new switch. You'd have to be a pretty heavy user for collisions to start to really come into play. In my building I have what I'd call a 'tree' topology. Router single cable up three floors to one switch. that switch splits out to more switches, one in each room...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i have purchase this desktop switch https://www.mercusys.co.in/product/details/ms108 but still the same, are there any setting, im using win 7

Comment: @Tetsujin i have purchase this desktop switch https://www.mercusys.co.in/product/details/ms108 but still the same, are there any setting, im using win 7

Comment: There are no settings on a consumer switch - they 'just work'.

Answer (score 1):

what everyone is trying to tell you is that you bought the wrong device for connecting things up. You don't want to "split" the signals going over the ethernet cable, you want to share them with all the devices. An ethernet "switch" does this. and they are quite cheap these days on Amazon. But what about your router? Most home routers have 3 or 4 ethernet "ports" or connectors that you can plug your printer and PC into, I would be surprised if yours didn't have them. You should be able to plug the pc and printer into the back of the router and be all set to go. If not, buy a switch.

Comment: i have purchase this desktop switch https://www.mercusys.co.in/product/details/ms108 but still the same, are there any setting, im using win 7

Comment: OK, so with all three devices connected to the  switch and same error then it sounds like an IP conflict. Did you manually configure the each device with their own IP address? I would give the router, printer and PC a hard-coded(static) address.  Then start pinging each other. Do you understand what I am suggesting, and do you know how to do it?